# Authentication between modules in Zend Framework

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-framework3

Currently I'm using ZF3 with two modules.

The first module **handles the authentication** of the users.
The second module **should use informations** about the authentication status of the users.

In Detail: The second module should verify if the user is logged in.
Depending on that status it should allow routing to certain Controllers.

E.g. in the template of the first module, I can use: `$this->auth()->isLoggedIn()`
But - of course - I'm not able to use auth() in the second modules templates.

I'm still learning ZF, so I don't know how to inform the second module about the status of the authentication. 
I guess it has something to do with ZFs ServiceManager or PluginManager, but I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Do you know how to create and inject services and events? Also: https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-authentication/ (If the answer to the first is "no", then you're in for a challenge ;-) ). Also, please show the code of what you tried, any errors etc. But, as a hint: you need to use the `AuthenticationService` (available in Factories via the ServiceManager (instance `$container`) by the alias `'AuthenticationService'`, e.g. `$container->get('AuthenticationService')`). gl & hf :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some explanations on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/zend_framework/zend_framework_service_manager.htm I solved it!

In FooControllerFactory::__invoke I used the Container to find the AuthManager

```
$authManager = $container->get(\Vendor\Auth\Manager::class);
```

Then, I returned it:

```
return new FooController($entityManager, $FooManager, $authManager);
```

(entityManager is from doctrine, FooManager is the manager for this model)

In FooController.php I added the authManager to the constructor

```
$this->authManager = $authManager;
```

Now I can get e.g. a username in any FooAction! :)

```
$this->authManager->getIdentity()->username
```

(replace "username" with the correct name of the user_id row)